# Get excerpt from $post->post_content

Tags: filters, excerpt, the-content

I am modifying the output of a plugin using a filter, and the $post variable is available to me, so I can display the post content like so:

```
<h3><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h3>
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
```

However, the above only displays the excerpt if content has been entered into the excerpt field. It doesn't show a truncated version of the content like it would if you were able to use "the_excerpt" or "get_the_excerpt". I've also tried:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_content ); ?>
```

But that just gets the full content of the post.

And I tried this:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post-ID)); ?>
```

But that returns nothing.

Is there a way to get the excerpt from the full content from $post when I can't use the_excerpt or get_the_excerpt?

Thank you!

Comment: By default, WordPress should be taking the first 55 words of `the_content` to serve as `the_excerpt` if none is explicitly defined.

Comment: Correct. But I can't use the_content or the_excerpt in this case. I have to use $post->post_content or $post->post_excerpt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), this will produce excerpt from `$post->post_content` directly:

```
<?php echo wp_trim_excerpt(); ?>
```

Read more [HERE](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_excerpt/).

### Alternative Solution:

**If you are not in the loop**, then, you may use similar implementation as done in the `wp_trim_excerpt` function:

```
$text = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
$text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
$text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
$excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 55 );
$excerpt_more = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
$text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
echo $text;
```